# How do I include application.conf in jar using gradle, and run it?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I want to make a jar file including "application.conf" through gradle like below.

```
$ gradle jar
```

I deploy it to a server and run it using the below command.

```
$ java -jar sample.jar
```

But an error occurred because "conf/application.conf" was not loaded and some variables could not be used.

This is the part of my "build.gradle"

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class' : mainClassName
  }
  from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

Does anybody have good ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is conf/application.conf located in your project? If you place it under src/main/resources/conf, then Gradle should pack it up into your jar by default.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to do the above, but the same error still occurred. I confirmed that "application.conf" was included in jar. (see below)  
    $ jar -tf sample.jar | grep application.conf  
    conf/application.conf